# How to correctly mock a Mongo DB repository for unit tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

I have a NestJS module representing my connection to the database as follows:

```js
@Module({exports: [MongoRepository]})
export class MongoRepository{
  findOne = async<T, Lean<T>>(Model: Model<T>, filter: Record<string, string>, lean = true): Promise<T | LeanT | null> { ... }

  findOneById = async ...

  updateOneById = async ...
}
```

For every domain entity I have a module defining a Controller, a Service, and dependencies.

Considering for example the `Conversation` module, that imports the `MongooseModule`:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'Conversation', schema: ConversationSchema },
    ]),
    MongoRepository,
    forwardRef(() => ChannelsModule),
  ],
  controllers: [ConversationsController],
  providers: [ConversationsService],
  exports: [ConversationsService],
})
export class ConversationsModule {}
```

I've been trying to write unit tests for the `ConversationsService`, but I'm unsure on how to write the testing module to be able to either mock the `MongoRepository` or just raise an in-memory MongoDB server to write to.

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
    mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    const uri = mongod.getUri();
    mongoConnection = (await connect(uri)).connection;
    conversationModel = mongoConnection.model(
      Conversation.name,
      ConversationSchema,
    );
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AppService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken(Conversation.name),
          useValue: conversationModel,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    conversationService = app.get<ConversationsService>(ConversationsService);
  });
```

By having this in the `conversation.service.spec.ts` file, it is unable to resolve all dependencies for the module, and I notice this is due to not having defined correctly the dependencies, however in every blog post or video I find there is a different structure to the unit tests.

How can I resolve the dependencies correctly for this?
What is the standard way to write unit tests for NestJS modules that have a single Repository (and not one per domain entity...?)

Comment: Does [this repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) help you?

Comment: TS is not my strength but can you create a fake repository (e.g. that stores data in a dictionary/map) and inject that fake repository in your service. The benefit of this is that your tests will be fast, but I would recommend that to also have some integration tests for your repository to ensure that it does interact with Mongo correctly.